# Cannot inject WCF Service dependency in ASP.NET MVC with StructureMap

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, structuremap

I have troubles injecting a WCF ServiceClient to a Controller's constructor using StructureMap.

I followed [Phil Haack's example on DI in ASP.NET MVC](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/12/07/tdd-and-dependency-injection-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx)

The WCF service I have is called LogService. It implements ILogService.

The StructureMap.config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<StructureMap>
<Assembly Name="Yakinix.Admin.Web" />
<Assembly Name="System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />

<PluginFamily Type="System.Web.Mvc.IController" Assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
    <Plugin Type="Yakinix.Admin.Web.Controllers.HomeController" ConcreteKey="home" Assembly="Yakinix.Admin.Web" />
</PluginFamily>

<PluginFamily Type="Yakinix.Admin.Web.LogService.ILogService" Assembly="Yakinix.Admin.Web" DefaultKey="WcfLogService">
    <Plugin Assembly="Yakinix.Admin.Web" Type="Yakinix.Admin.Web.LogService.LogServiceClient" ConcreteKey="WcfLogService" />
</PluginFamily>
</StructureMap>
```

The error getting thrown is this:

> StructureMap Exception Code:  200
>   Could not find an InstanceMemento for
>   the requested InstanceKey
>   "WcfLogService" of PluginFamily
>   Yakinix.Admin.Web.LogService.ILogService

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I can't have an exact answer to your question but at dimecasts.com there's a screencast that details how to add IOC support to your WCF Services. It's a worth try.

http://dimecasts.net/Casts/CastDetails/150

Comment: I don't think that is what he is asking. He wants to inject a "WCF Service" into "something", whereas that cast shows an example of injecting "something" into WCF Service.